# Usage of @project.id@ in a custom spring-boot-starter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

We have a set of `Spring Boot` projects, which share a custom `spring-boot-starter` for logging. This logger uses the property `app.name = @project.artifactId@` for configuration. So we have to repeat this in each of our projects. Is it possible to move this in the starter, to avoid the repetition?

Comment: Why do you want to name all the projects with the same name?

Comment: No. The projects have different names.

Comment: Where is this property `app.name` defined currently. It would be helpful if you can provide the structure of your project.